# Round Brackets Around "Typedef" Data Type

Tags: objective-c

What round brackets do to a typedef in the line `optionAction = attempter(option);` ? 
Is that casting?

The full code:

```
- (id<ISFModalMessageView>)modalMessageWithError:(NSError *)error recoveryAttempter:(SFErrorRecoveryAttempter)attempter
{
if ([self shouldNotifyUserForError:error] && [self typeForError:error] == SFErrorTypeAlert) 
{ 
NSString *title = [self titleForError:error];
NSString *message = [self messageForError:error];
SFAlertMessageView *alert = [[SFAlertMessageView alloc]initWithTitle:title message:message image:nilcancelButton:@"Cancel"];

SFErrorRecoveryOption option = [self recoveryOptionForError:error];
if (option != SFErrorRecoveryOptionUndefiend) 
{ 
NSString *optionTitle = [self titleForRecoveryOptionOfError:error];     
SFModalMessageAction optionAction = nil;

if (attempter) {
optionAction = attempter(option);  // This Part
}
if (optionTitle.notEmpty && optionAction) {
[alert addActionButtonWithTitle:optionTitle action:optionAction];
} 
}
return alert;
}
return nil;
}
```

SFErrorRecoveryOption:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, SFErrorRecoveryOption) {
SFErrorRecoveryOptionUndefiend = 0,

SFErrorRecoveryOptionTryAgain,
SFErrorRecoveryOptionReport,
SFErrorRecoveryOptionSignIn,
SFErrorRecoveryOptionSignUp,
SFErrorRecoveryOptionReset,
SFErrorRecoveryOptionSignInFacebook,
};
```

SFModalMessageAction:

```
typedef void (^ SFModalMessageAction)() ;
```

SFErrorRecoveryAttempter:

```
typedef SFModalMessageAction (^ SFErrorRecoveryAttempter)(SFErrorRecoveryOption option);
```

Comment: Kinda hard to tell when you don't show us the typedef or tell us what is typedefed.

Comment: What additional typedef's should I provide?

Comment: Any typedefs at all would be a step forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely SFErrorRecoveryAttempter is typedefed to some [block type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) and line in question

```
attempter(option);
```

is just calling a block passed to your method as parameter. Note that calling a nil block will result in exception, so `if (attempter)` check is added